# How to resize dynamically allocated QPushButtons in QGridLayout?

Tags: c++, qt, qpushbutton, qgridlayout

I am trying to fix the size of a grid of `QPushButton` dynamically allocated. It seems that nothing I do have impact on the final result.

I have tried multiple solutions such as `setSizePolicy`, `setFixedSize`, `setStretch` and more. Also it seems that when I add more `QPushButton` in the grid, they expand beyond the border of the layout instead of resizing the buttons within it. My code:

```
for (int i=0;i<xGridCount;++i)
{
    for (int j=0;j<yGridCount;++j)
    {
        QString idStrI;
        QString idStrJ;
        idStrI.setNum(abs(xGridCount - (i)));
        idStrJ.setNum(abs(yGridCount - (j)));
        QString nameStr = idStrI + "," + idStrJ;
        TrayLayoutButton *btn = new TrayLayoutButton();
        btn->setObjectName(nameStr);
        btn->setState(TrayLayoutButton::NONE);

        btn->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Fixed,QSizePolicy::Fixed);
        btn->setFixedSize(QSize(50,50));

        connect(btn,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SLOT (handleButton()));

        ui->gridLayout->addWidget(btn,i,j);
        ui->gridLayout->setSpacing(0);
    }
}
setLayout(ui->gridLayout);
```

All advice are welcome.

Comment: You realize that you asked how to *fix the size of a grid of QPushButton* and at the same you expect *the layout to resize the buttons within it* ? Make your mind clear about what you want to achieve before trying to play with the layouts, it is in the end quite simple but you need to know clearly what behavior you want.

Comment: As a primary objective I want to be able to put in any number of Qpushbuttons into the QgridLayout and scale the size of the buttons with respect to the layout size. Such that all buttons are always visible.
Making the buttons square is secondary. ty